# How to extract product weight from this HTML

Tags: java, regex

My HTML looks like this:

```
<td class="main"><b>Product Weight  (2.83 lbs in 1 container)</b></td>
```

I need to get the value 2.83 from the HTML.

Need help with the regex.

I have this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(

  "<td\\sclass=\"main\"><b>Product\\sWeight\\s\\s((?:\\d+\\.)?\\d+ \\w{3})");
```

But doesn't seem to be working.

Am I missing an escape or something?

**Update**

If the brackets are an issue, do I just do ( or on the inner brackets also?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing an escape on the literal parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

For getting specific html-tags I recommend HTML-parsers over Regex.
You could for example use [this](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) html-parser.

Comment: Good instinct, but the OP isn't trying to parse HTML, just scrape data that happens to be surrounded by tags.

Comment: +1 on htmlparser, you may also want to look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)
Also see the many answers on SO warning against trying to use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: You're right, if it this single data extraction is everything to be done, setting up a parser would be a bit overkill.